# Does Speed-Gro fertilizer affect the growth of repeating crops?

Tags: stardew-valley

Speed-Gro fertilizer increases the growth rate of crops by 10%, while the Deluxe version increases growth rate by 25%.

My question is, **does the fertilizer also increase the rate at which repeating crops grow (i.e. the crops that grow after the 1st set is harvested)?**

By repeating crops, I mean crops like corn, blueberries, cranberries, etc.

So, for example, blueberries normally take 13 days to fully mature, but after 13 days, they continue to grow new berries every 4 days. Will Deluxe Speed-Gro fertilizer reduce the repeat growth rate to 3 days (75% of 4)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer: no  [according to the wiki](http://stardewvalleywiki.com/Fertilizer)

Long answer: Speed Gro only affects the rate at which the plant "matures" and not the rate at which it "produces crops". For most plants like pumpkins and melons, these are the same age so it doesn't matter, but since blueberries ,cranberries, etc all produce multiple times it is an important distinction.